# Incorrect number of parameters for function IF() what are the three required parameters?

Tags: workflow, formula

This is the if statement i am trying to create for a workflow:

```
IF( UnitPrice < Discount_Floor__c ,  Approval_Required__c   = true )
```

it tells it expects 3 parameters and its only getting 2. Does anyone know what the 3rd parameter needs to be? what is the correct synax for this?

Thank you

Comment: Is this for the workflow criteria formula, or a field update formula? In a workflow criteria formula, you usually don't need an IF() - the formula itself should return TRUE or FALSE. IF() returns arbitrary values depending on a condition. In other words, if what you want is for the workflow to fire when the unit price is less than the discount floor,  then drop  the IF() and just use: `UnitPrice < Discount_Floor__c`

Answer (score 4):

For IF, you need to provide the return value if the test succeeds AND if the test fails:

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

"Checks whether a condition is true, and returns one value if TRUE and another value if FALSE."

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: Thank you, So basically i just need to add Approval_Required__c = false? Is there any kind of documentation for this that you could link me to? Much appreciated!

Comment: Added it to the post. Good luck :)

Comment: This is useful info, but using if here is like using a hammer when you need a saw. See other answer fit the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a misconception of what `IF` does. You do not specify an action, but rather an output. For your criteria, you should not use `IF` at all, simply evaluate the logical expression and specify a `Field Update` that will then perform the action you desire. In fact, if you do not need the field to be writeable, you can even use just a formula. All you need for your criteria/formula is this part:

```
UnitPrice < Discount_Floor__c
```

Because `IF(Checkbox__c, TRUE, FALSE)` evaluates the same as `Checkbox__c`.